# Срабатывал при клике

Tags: javascript

Здравствуйте, есть меню, когда наводишь появляется одно подменю, как сделать, чтобы оно появлялась не при наводке а при клике, а при клике на пустое пространство просто закрывалось

```js
  if ($(window).width() > 1220) {
  $('.top-menu li:has(.hidden-menu)').hover(function() {
    $(this).find('.hidden-menu').fadeToggle(200);
    $(this).toggleClass('menuactive');
  }); 
  } else {
  $('.top-menu li:has(.hidden-menu) > a').click(function() {
    $(this).parent().find('.hidden-menu').fadeToggle(200);
    $(this).parent().toggleClass('menuactive');
    return false;
  }); 
  };
```

Comment: так и заменить hover на click

Comment: я заменил, но оно не закрывается при клике на пустое место

Comment: можно повесить событие "click" на "document" которое и будет закрывать ваше меню, с условием что клик был не по элементам меню.

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/off/

Comment: Помогите пожалуйста прикрепить к этому скрипту